# Pandas DataFrame Table Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, replace

I'd like to append the stock basic information in the pandas table using index key.
so, I set the index df.set_index(['code', 'date'])
but, the result was always replaced even though the other code and date data.
Could you let me know why always the new row data is replaced after deleted?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([list(stock_info_dict.values())], columns=['code', 'name', 'date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'numstocks', 'diffPrices', 'diffrates'])

    df.set_index(['code', 'date'])

    filepath = os.path.abspath("D:\\PycharmProject\\202007Test\\chart\\daily.db")
    con = sqlite3.connect(filepath)
    df.to_sql('stock_info', con, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: You need to re-assign your set_index statement `df = df.set_index(['code','date'])`

Comment: As Scott mentioned, set_index returns a new df and leaves self untouched by default. You can change that with parameter `inplace=True`. I recommend you keep a bookmark to Pandas' doc and use it as first reference. They have a great user guide. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Comment: fundamentally python and pandas is functional,  so no side effects.  if you want the result of a function `df = df.set_index()` or you don't.  `df.set_index()` does not have side effects unless you pass `inplace=True`